# Not allowing duplicates in dynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to insert a row using following piece of code:

```java
Item item = new Item().withPrimaryKey("id", id).withString(
                "owner", owner);

if (properties != null) {
    item.withMap("property", properties);
}

Expected expected = new Expected(id).notExist();

return table.putItem(item, expected).toString();
```

This is not supposed to update if entry with "id" with provided id already exists in the table. However, this is still updating the entry in the table with the new values.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you give an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with an item you do not think should be updated?

Comment: you need a conditional put

Comment: @mkobit In the example i gave, there are 2 fields: id and property. Id is the hash key. Now suppose i added a entry with id="vike1" and some property. Now i am trying to add another entry with same hash,"vike1". To avoid this, i have put expected(id).notExist(), so that it doesn't enter the data if id already exists. However, it is updating the existing data with hash "vike1" .Hope you get complete scenario.

Comment: @Mircea I am trying the same thing by using Expected expected = new Expected(id).notExist();  Is there any other way i can do that?

Comment: @vivek `Expected` is a [legacy parameter, you should use `ConditionExpression` instead](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html#DDB-PutItem-request-Expected). This still doesn't explain why you are able to update the item. Could you provide a *full example* to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: @mkobit I am not sure what more info you need.
The complete scenario will be, execute above piece of code twice with same id but different property map. The final saved data in the table will be that of second run, although it will not supposed to save anything as data for that id is already present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are providing the attribute value to the `Expected` constructor when the [constructor is for the **attribute name**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/document/Expected.html#Expected(java.lang.String)).

> public Expected(java.lang.String attrName)

You should change from using the parameter/hash key value `id`

```
Expected expected = new Expected(id).notExist();
```

to use the attribute name

```
Expected expected = new Expected("id").notExist();
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I interpreted the statement wrong. Yes, we need to provide the attribute name not the value.